# Java regular expression * issue

Tags: java, regex

Why does this regular expression trigger the index of "" ?

```
Enter your regex: a*
Enter input string to search: aaaaa
I found the text "aaaaa" starting at index 0 and ending at index 5.
I found the text "" starting at index 5 and ending at index 5
```

Comment: `a*` means "zero or more of `a`". So it can match an empty string. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Yes sir, but why does it not stop after finding aaaa as there is no more characters to match?

Comment: Where does this output come from? The question should be not "why does it match empty string" (it obviously does match the empty string), but rather: why doesn't it keep matching empty strings indefinitely?

Answer (score 1):

From Java API documentation (class Pattern, 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html):

X* - X, **zero** or more times

So the empty String matches `a` appearing zero times. If you need at least one occurrence of `a`, use `a+` (it means that `a` needs to appear at least once).

Answer (score 1):

The extra empty matched because the regex engine will not only check each character, but also the "empty space" between characters.

When `a*` matches all the a's, there is still a position at the end that is not checked. It checks that and says "oh, there is 0 a's, so it should match", hence giving you an empty match.

First match:

[image]

Second match:

[image]

I think what you really meant is this regex here:

```
a+|^$
```

It either matches one or more a's or an empty string.